# Proof check on $I (\lim \sup E_n(w)) = \lim \sup I_{E_n}(w)$, where $I$ is the indicator function.

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

[image]

I proceed by cases:

$ \lim \sup I_{E_n}(w) := \lim_m \downarrow \{ \sup_{n>m} I_{E_n}(w) \}$ this is $0$ only if $w \not \in E_n  \forall n > m$.

At the right of the equality we have $I_{\lim \sup E_n}(w) := I_{(\bigcap_m \bigcup_{n >m } E_n)}(w)$ And when $w \not \in E_n  \forall n > m$ we have that $w \not \in \bigcap_m \bigcup_{n >m } E_n$ because I can always find an $m$ s.t. $ w \not \in \bigcup_{n >m } E_n$.

Thus when one side is zero the other is also. Now because there are only two possible values for each side this means that when one side of the equality is one also the other will be one.

I am unsure if this proof works, or if I should add additional justifications in some passages. What would you do? Any more elegant proofs?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\omega\in\Omega$. If $\mathsf 1_{\limsup_{n\to\infty}E_n}(\omega)=1$, then $$\omega\in\limsup_{n\to\infty}\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k. $$
Hence for each $n$, there exists $k\geqslant n$ such that $\omega\in E_k$. Therefore
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathsf 1_{E_n}(\omega) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geqslant n} \mathsf 1_{E_k}(\omega)=1. $$

If $\mathsf 1_{\limsup_{n\to\infty}}(\omega)=0$, then there exists an $n$ such that $\omega\notin E_k$ for all $k\geqslant n$. Hence

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathsf 1_{E_n}(\omega)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geqslant n} = 0. $$